# Modal box content depends of custom field

Tags: php, html, lightbox, advanced-custom-fields, featherlight.js

I'm trying to display 2 different content in a modal box using [featherlight.js](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). It's very simple :

If there is an 'image', it displays the 'image', otherwise if there is a 'soundcloud url', it displays a 'soundcloud url' iframe.
But it doesn't work!

Here is my [website](http://www.skuar.com)

And here is the code

```
<div id="post"> 
    <a href="#" data-featherlight="#featherlight">      
        <div class="img"> 
            <div class="art-overlay"> 
                <div class="small"> 
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/skuar_small.png" alt="skuar" /> 
                </div> 
            </div>   

    <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); 
        } 
    ?> 

<?php 

if( get_field( 'image' ) ) { ?>
<?php the_field( 'image' ); ?>
  <?php } 
  else { ?>
<iframe width="600" height="166" scrolling="no" class="lightbox" class="frame" id="featherlight" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=<?php the_field( 'music' ); ?>&color=1b1e25&theme_color=1b1e25&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false"></iframe>
<?php endif; ?><?php } ?>      
        </div> 
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where to click on your site?

Comment: On the S logo in the center of each thumbnail...it should be the all thumbnail but I have probably made a mistake with the code so only the logo works so far :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look now, using [featherlight.js](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) it works : [skuar.com](http://www.skuar.com)

Just because I removed the overlay on thumbnails!
Is there any way to add this very simple overlay?

```
    <div class="art-overlay">
        <div class="small">
            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/skuar_small.png" alt="skuar" />
        </div>
```

```
.art-overlay {

    display: flex;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
    transition: opacity 300ms;

    .small {
        margin: auto;
        width: 59px;
        height: 75px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    }
}

#post:hover .art-overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```